# Hibernate Query Syntax exception hql error with entity java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have a query where i am joining two entities java (tables ) Command and User.  I create sql hql query with left join and i get an **org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token error**
I think that i have a problem with my left join syntax  and also my second select.
My entities

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {

private int idUser;

private String login;

private String password;

private List<Command> commands = new ArrayList<>();


public User() { }

public User( String login, String password ) {
    super();
    this.setLogin( login );
    this.setPassword( password );
}

@Id
@Column(name = "USER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, scale = 0)
public int getIdUser() {
    return idUser;
}

@Column(name = "USER_LOGIN", nullable = false)
public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

@Column(name = "USER_PASSWORD", nullable = false)
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "utilisateur")
public List<Command> getCommands() {
    return commands;
}

public String toString() {
    return this.idUser + ": " + this.login + "/" + this.password 
         ;
}
```

}

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="Commands")
public class Command {


private int idCommand;

private User utilisateur;

private Date commandDate;


public Command() {}

public Command( User user, Date commandDate ) {
    this.setUser( user );
    this.setCommandDate( commandDate );
}

@Id
@Column(name = "CMD_Id", unique = true, nullable = false, scale = 0)
public int getIdCommand() {
    return idCommand;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
public User getUtilisateur() {
    return user;
}

public void setUtilisateur(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

@Column(name = "CMD_DATE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
public Date getCommandDate() {
    return commandDate;
}

public void setCommandDate(Date commandDate) {
    this.commandDate = commandDate;
}

public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append( "Commande de >> " ).append( this.user )
           .append( " - " ).append( this.commandDate ).append( "\n" );
    return builder.toString();
}
```

}

And my hql query

```
select us.login,us.password 
from User us  left join Command cmd on us.idUser = cmd.utilisateur.idUser
AND us.idUser not in (SELECT utilisateur.idUser from Command )   
ORDER BY us.idUser desc
```

I don't know what is the problem with my hql query. I Use the entity java in my hql query. AnyOne can i tell me how can i write correctly my hql query with a good syntax hql.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the users login and password of users without commands the following might help

```
select us.login,us.password 
from User us 
where us.idUser not in (select c.user.idUser from Command c)   
order by us.idUser desc
```